# Play Animation using AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine, android-animation, sprite-sheet, texturepacker

I'm new to AndEngine.
I want to simply play an animation on the center of the screen by using sprite sheet (I'm using TexturePacker for creating sprite sheet) can anyone help me with this requirement?! I didn't find any good complete tutorial for the same! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

First load Sprite sheet as follows:

```
 TexturePackLoader texturePackLoader = new TexturePackLoader(this.getAssets(), this.getTextureManager());
 TexturePack gameTexPack = texturePackLoader.loadFromAsset("gfx/JumpingJack.xml", "gfx/");
 gameTexPack.loadTexture();
 TexturePackTextureRegionLibrary mTextureRegionLibrary = gameTexPack.getTexturePackTextureRegionLibrary();
```

You can play animation of frames as follows:

```
public static AnimatedSprite getAnimatedSprite(int textRegId, int framesCount){ 
    int counter=0;

    ITextureRegion[] iTextureRegions = new ITextureRegion[framesCount];

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        ITextureRegion textureRegion = GameActivity.activity.mTextureRegionLibrary.get(textRegId+i).deepCopy();
        iTextureRegions[counter] = textureRegion;
        counter++;
    }

    ITiledTextureRegion tiledTextureRegion = new TiledTextureRegion(iTextureRegions[0].getTexture(), iTextureRegions);
    AnimatedSprite animSprite = new AnimatedSprite(0, 0, tiledTextureRegion, GameActivity.activity.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    return animSprite;
}
```

Comment: Check it  the way i have done.

Comment: Is that GameActivity a class from AndEngine library? Can you please upload your full source code.?

Comment: No, it is not a lib class.Remove that GameActivity code and use it